# Same algorithms with NSMutableArray and SetImage with different names work differently

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, mutable

So I have a problem.

I have :

```
NSMutableArray *photos_imagesArray;
NSMutableArray *myPhotos_imagesArray;
```

Declared in the .h file inside of `@interface EXViewController`.

What I do is:

For one view - `photos_viewController` - I take image data from `photos_imagesArray` and use setImage on an `UIImageView` on this view. Everything works.

Now, when I do exactly the same thing but with the `myPhotos_viewController` and with the `myPhotos_imagesArray` - setImage does not fire up and `myPhotos_imagesArray` gets emptied.

Why the heck is this working this way? I have two very identical algorithms working in two as well identical Views and yet I get different results. All that is different is a couple of names. XCode isn't even showing me any errors.

Update 1 (Shared the code):

The place in the EXViewController.h where I declared the mutable arrays.

```
@interface EXViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIImagePickerController *upload_imagePickerCamera;
    UIImagePickerController *upload_imagePickerLibrary;
    UIImage *upload_imageUploaded;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *upload_imageViewUploadedImage;

    // Photos Currently viewed
    NSInteger _photoIndex;
    NSMutableArray *photos_imagesArray;
    NSMutableArray *myPhotos_imagesArray;
}
```

And the functions:

For the part that works -

```
// PHOTOS

-(void)goToPhotos {

    [photos_imagesArray removeAllObjects];

    _photoIndex = 0;

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewControllerPhotos = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerPhotos"];
    [self  presentViewController:viewControllerPhotos animated:true completion:nil];

    PFQuery *query_photos = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];
    [query_photos orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query_photos findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            // Copy objects array to photos array
            photos_imagesArray = [objects mutableCopy];

            // Set Current photo
            [self photos_setCurrentPhoto];


        } else {

            NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];

        }
    }];
}

-(void)photos_setCurrentPhoto{

    if ([photos_imagesArray count] != 0) {

    PFFile *userImageFile = photos_imagesArray[_photoIndex][@"imageFile"];
    [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
            [self.photos_imageViewCurrent setImage:image];
        }
    }];

    }
}
```

And for the part that doesn't -

```
// MY PHOTOS

-(void)myPhotos_goToMyPhotos{

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewControllerPhotos = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerMyPhotos"];
    [self  presentViewController:viewControllerPhotos animated:true completion:^{

        PFQuery *query_photos = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Photo"];

        [query_photos whereKey:@"userId" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].objectId];
        [query_photos orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];

        [query_photos findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                _photoIndex = 0;

                // Copy objects array to photos array
                myPhotos_imagesArray = [objects mutableCopy];

                NSLog(@"%i",[myPhotos_imagesArray count]);

                // Set Current photo
                [self myPhotos_setCurrentPhoto];


            } else {

                NSString *errorString = [error userInfo][@"error"];
                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:errorString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];

            }
        }];

    }];

}

-(void)myPhotos_setCurrentPhoto{

    if ([myPhotos_imagesArray count] != 0) {

        // Set photo in image view
        PFFile *userImageFile = myPhotos_imagesArray[_photoIndex][@"imageFile"];
        [userImageFile getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *imageData, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
                self.myPhotos_imageViewCurrentPhoto.image = image;
            }
        }];

    }
}
```

P.S I tried the algorithm inside and outside the completion callback - same results.

Update 2 (added the whole EXViewController.h file):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Parse/Parse.h>

@interface EXViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> {
    UIImagePickerController *upload_imagePickerCamera;
    UIImagePickerController *upload_imagePickerLibrary;
    UIImage *upload_imageUploaded;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *upload_imageViewUploadedImage;

    // Photo Currently viewed
    NSInteger _photoIndex;
    NSMutableArray *photos_imagesArray;
    NSMutableArray *myPhotos_imagesArray;
}

// Login Form
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *login_fieldEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *login_fieldPassword;
- (IBAction)login_buttonSignInAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)login_buttonForgotAction:(id)sender;


// Sign Up Form
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *signup_fieldEmail;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *signup_fieldPassword;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *signup_fieldCountry;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *signup_fieldSex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *signup_fieldYear;
- (IBAction)buttonSignupAction:(id)sender;

// Photos
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *photos_imageViewCurrent;
- (IBAction)photos_buttonRatePlus:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)photos_buttonRateMinus:(id)sender;


// Menu
- (IBAction)menu_buttonSignOutAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)menu_buttonMyPhotos:(id)sender;


// Upload Photo
- (IBAction)upload_buttonTakePhoto:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)upload_buttonPhotoAlbum:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)upload_buttonUpload:(id)sender;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIProgressView *upload_progressViewUpload;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *upload_labelImageUploaded;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *upload_gravity;

// My Photos
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *myPhotos_imageViewCurrentPhoto;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myPhotos_labelRating;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *myPhotos_labelVotes;
- (IBAction)myPhotos_buttonNext:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)myPhotos_buttonPrevious:(id)sender;



@end
```

Comment: Obviously it has nothing to do with the names. Make them properties and set breakpoints on them, that should allow you to see what is happening or not. Or just put breakpoints on all the lines that make changes to and access the one that does not work correctly.

Comment: hard to say without more information. you should add some breakpoints and logging in your code to check your assumptions.

Comment: Share some code please.

Comment: Is all the code you posted in the EXViewController?

Comment: FWIW, your setImage syntax is different between the two.  I can't see how it would matter, unless the blocks are retaining different pointers because of the different syntax.

Comment: @rdelmar basically yes - first part is in the .h file and the rest is in the EXViewController.m file.

Comment: @stevesliva it was just my "lottery" modification in hope that maybe it would work that way.. I was thinking maybe it is because the view isn't loaded when the functions are called. Sorry for the question in a comment but do you or anyone else no a surer way to call some functions after the view is loaded for 100%?

Comment: @AlexLeu you can call methods after the view has been loaded within the `viewDidLoad`, or after it has been added to the view hierarchy with `viewDidAppear:`.
---
Back to the original question: your query is different for the two image arrays, are you sure your second query is even returning anything?

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh yes I'm sure. I checked it a lot of times with NSLog

Comment: @AlexLeu is there a particular reason the instance that does not work happens in the completion block, while the version that does is outside of the completion block?  That would seem to be my first thought as to a big way these are different.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh thanks for the suggestion but originally it was exactly as the first working one. It was afterwards when I started experimenting, in order to make this thing work, I moved the code into the completion block.

Comment: @AlexLeu okay, so then my next thought (without seeing the rest of your `.m` of course) is that you have some difference in your `viewWill/DidAppear:` or `viewWill/DidDisappear:`. My thought being that you may have in one spot cleared the array within either of those methods (or a method they call). Another thought, is that there is some threading issue -- does Parse ensure that the block is executed on the main thread?

Comment: Where is myPhotos_imageViewCurrentPhoto defined? You're calling it on self, but I don't see any such image view in EXViewController. Is that the image view in the controller you're presenting?

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh great guess with threads! Indeed it is running it's data retrieving functions in a background thread. Now I am running through their documentation to find a way to get data NOT in background.

Comment: @rdelmar I added the full EXViewController.h file to the question - myPhotos_imageViewCurrentPhoto is defined there - if it wouldn't I guess I would get an error :/

Comment: @AlexLeu you could just use a `dispatch_async(...)` and force code to execute on the main thread within the block. But that doesn't feel like the correct answer as one block seems to work and the other does not.

Comment: dispatch_async( ... ) did not help as well.. guess i'll go the stupid way and will rewrite the whole non working part with alternative stuff